# How to not include a particular element from soup.select()?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I use `soup.select('.c-w a')` to select elements. Inside `c-w`, there is `c-s` of which I would like not to include in this selection.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div class="c-w">
  <div class="c-s">
    <a href="sound://english-french/sound/M000001099.mp3"><img class="soundpng" src="file://sound.png"/></a>
</div></div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('.c-w a'):
        a['href'] = 'entry://'
```

and the result is

```
<div class="c-w">
<div class="c-s">
<a href="entry://"><img class="soundpng" src="file://sound.png"/></a>
</div></div>
```

My goal is to not include `.c-s .a` in this process of replacement. I mean when the search meet `c-s`, it will ignore this element and search in other ones. Could you please elaborate on how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample input (e.g. snippet of HTML code) and expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I'm sorry for this sloppy. Please see my edit.

Comment: So if I understand your right, you want to replace `href=` of all `<a>` links but not the ones inside `class=c-s` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Exactly ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, you can use `.find_parent()` to determine if the `<a>` tag is inside tag with `class="c-s"`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div class="c-w">
  <div class="c-s">
    <a href="sound://english-french/sound/M000001099.mp3"><img class="soundpng" src="file://sound.png"/></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="THIS I WANT TO REPLACE">...</a>
  </div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('.c-w a'):
    if a.find_parent(class_='c-s'):
        continue
    a['href'] = 'entry://'

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<div class="c-w">
 <div class="c-s">
  <a href="sound://english-french/sound/M000001099.mp3">
   <img class="soundpng" src="file://sound.png"/>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <a href="entry://">
   ...
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

EDIT: To exclude both `.c-s` and `.c-v`, you can do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div class="c-w">
  <div class="c-s">
    <a href="sound://english-french/sound/M000001099.mp3"><img class="soundpng" src="file://sound.png"/></a>
  </div>

  <div class="c-v">
    <a href="sound://english-french/sound/M000001099.mp3"><img class="soundpng" src="file://sound.png"/></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="THIS I WANT TO REPLACE">...</a>
  </div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('.c-w a'):
    if a.find_parent(class_=['c-s', 'c-v']):
        continue
    a['href'] = 'entry://'

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<div class="c-w">
 <div class="c-s">
  <a href="sound://english-french/sound/M000001099.mp3">
   <img class="soundpng" src="file://sound.png"/>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="c-v">
  <a href="sound://english-french/sound/M000001099.mp3">
   <img class="soundpng" src="file://sound.png"/>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <a href="entry://">
   ...
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works fine. I would like to ask further if I can add more elements, not just `c-s`. For example, not search inside both `c-s` and `c-v`.

Comment: It seems to me that your code only works in case `c-s` is a class. For generality, I try `a.find_parent(_=['.d_sound', '.ex']):` but it does not works. I mean in case we have the path `audio .sound` and `main .ex`, i.e `ex` is of id, not class.

Comment: @LAD `.find_parent()` doesn't accept CSS selectors. You can do `if a.find_parent(class_=["d_sound"]) or a.find_parent(id=["ex"]):`

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated help! This issue is so delicate to me.